# How to quickly cut a 3D space with a plane in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D matrix in python:

```
mat = np.zeros((512,512,480))
```

The index of each element is the coordinates of each point in space.

And a plane:

```
center = np.array([251.7, 150.2, 200.1])
normal = np.array([-0.07017233, -0.99284769,  0.09658831])
```

I want to have a mask of `mat`. The value of each element is `1` if the corresponding point is on the same side as the direction of the normal, otherwise, set the value to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the most efficient solution that I could think:

```
center = np.array([251.7, 150.2, 200.1])
normal = np.array([-0.07017233, -0.99284769,  0.09658831])

x = np.arange(512)
y = np.arange(512)
z = np.arange(480)

xmesh, ymesh, zmesh = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

xm = xmesh - center[0]
ym = ymesh - center[1]
zm = zmesh - center[2]

p = xm*normal[0] + ym*normal[1] + zm*normal[2]

mat = np.where(p>0,1,0)
```

This follows the same mathematical thinking that a described in the other answer, but, with the meshgrids and the np.where command we can check the location of the point in relation to the plane in parallel.

I implemented a version with 3 four loops and it runs in more than 6 minutes, this version runs in 30 seconds. I hope that it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let n = (nx, ny, nz) be your normal vector and c = (xo,yo,zo) a point of the plane.

And given a point P whose position vector is r = (x,y,z).

If the dot product of (r-c) and n be positive, the point P is above the plane, otherwise, the point is below the plane.

You can check this by analytical geometry. But this is just the math, one way to implement this is by doing a loop through the indices of the matrix, making a vector of them, subtracting the `center`, and then using `np.dot()` to make a dot product with `normal` inside an if statement that will decide if the value will be `0` or `1`.

Comment: The problem is, doing this way is very slow. I am looking for a more efficient way to do it.